# Drawing form graphics to picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

I don't know how to explain properly but maybe the code will make it more clear.
`title1_Box` is a `PictureBox` and I'm trying to draw the rectangle 'item' into `title1_Box`.
`Rect` is a list containing rectangles.

It's probably something stupid. I'm new to programming.
Thanks in advance.

```
private void UpdateTiles(string path)
{
    Image imgsrc = Image.FromFile(@path);
    Image imgdst = new Bitmap(imgsrc.Width / 2, imgsrc.Height);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(imgdst))
    { 
        for (int imgIndex = 0; imgIndex <= imgsrc.Width / 32; imgIndex++)
        {
            rects.Add(new Rectangle((imgIndex * 32), 0,
                (32 + (imgIndex * 32)), 32));
        }
        foreach (Rectangle item in rects)
        {
             gr.DrawImage(imgsrc,
                item);
             tile1_Box.RectangleToScreen(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a lot farther afield than you want to go, but I would start off by suggesting that you create a class for your rectangle so that you can leverage its `Paint` event, meaning that each one draws itself.  Creating a `Graphics` object as you are doing is highly volatile, and harder to keep drawn.  It could be erased by an `Invalidate()` call before you even see it.

Comment: You haven't done anything to make the image visible to the user.  Add `tile1_Box.Image = imgdst;` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this from the `Paint` event, passing **its** `Graphics` object into your function:

```
private void title1_Box_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{   UpdateTiles(e.Graphics, path);  }

private void UpdateTiles(Graphics gr, string path)
{
 //.. now you gr instead of any local Graphics..!!
```

Also you should do an

```
title1_Box.Invalidate();
```

wherever you called your *UpdateTiles* so far. Thuis will call the `Paint` event, which also **needs** to be called, whenever windows detects a need to repaint.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Graphic class instance directly from the picterBox instances:

```
Graphics gr = title1_Box.CreateGraphics();
```

What ever you do with gr will take place in title1_Box, so you can draw directly into your pictureBox now.